# Where is the autorelease pool for OS X application created and drained?

Tags: macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

I'm refactoring my OS X application for ARC. Opening the main.m file, I was sure I would find the Autorelease Pool instantiation and drain (like iOS projects) but to my big surprise it wasn't there.

So my first question is:

- Where is the main Autorelease Pool?

My next question is:

- If the main Autorelease Pool isn't created, do I need to create it? Or are autoreleased objects freed in some automagical way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your main.m file should have the following call:

```
NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);
```

[`NSApplicationMain()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSApplicationMain) is responsible for creating the application, i.e., an instance of [`NSApplication`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which in turn is responsible for creating autorelease pools:

> The NSApplication class sets up autorelease pools (instances of the NSAutoreleasePool class) during initialization and inside the event loop—specifically, within its initialization (or sharedApplication) and run methods.

This means that, in the general case, you shouldn’t have to worry about creating autorelease pools since `NSApplication` already does that in both the initialisation and in the event loop. There are situations where creating your own autorelease pools might be necessary/desirable, e.g. a method that has a loop that creates many autoreleased objects. In this case, it’s a good idea to have an autorelease pool for each loop iteration.

Comment: I have NSString *a = [NSString string]; line in main function and i am getting *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x7fff703fd190 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking why?

Comment: @Parag If you’re doing it in `main()`, then you’re not calling (or haven’t called yet) `NSApplicationMain()`, which in turn doesn’t create `NSApplication`, which creates autorelease pools automatically. If you’re not using `NSApplication`, you need to create your own autorelease pools.

Comment: return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv); statement is also in my main() function.int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 NSString *a = [NSString string];
    return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
}

Comment: @Parag That’s why I wrote _(or haven’t called yet)_. If you’re creating a string **before** `NSApplicationMain()` is called, there is no autorelease pool in place and you should create your own.

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case, this topic is very well-covered in Apple's documentation. For example, check out the *What Happens in the main Function* section of [this Cocoa Fundamentals Guide chapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/AddingBehaviortoaCocoaProgram/AddingBehaviorCocoa.html). To quote the part relevant to this question (already explained by Bavarious):

> The main function in almost all Cocoa applications is extremely
>   simple. In Mac OS X, it consists of only one function call.

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

> The **NSApplicationMain function** creates the application
>   object, **sets up an autorelease pool**, loads the initial user interface
>   from the main nib file, and runs the application, thereby requesting
>   it to begin handling events received on the main event loop.